# User with required role is rejected

Tags: java, spring-security

I have the following configuration file:

```java
//AUTHORIZATION
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable();
    http
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home", "/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/example1/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN_ACCESS, EXAMPLE1_USER, EXAMPLE1_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/example2/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN_ACCESS, EXAMPLE2_USER, EXAMPLE2_ADMIN)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("pass")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds(600)
            .key("secretKey")
            .rememberMeParameter("checkRememberMe");
}
```

I log in with this user, note that it has `ROLE_ADMIN` (basically, access everything):

```json
{
    "username": "test",
    "pass": "test",
    "roles": "ROLE_ADMIN",
    "permissions": "",
    "company": "test"
}
```

The login takes place correctly through a Thymeleaf form. However, whenever I try to access an endpoint locked behind a role, I get an error 500.

I tried different annotations, as you can see here, in the controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/example1")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_EXAMPLE1_USER', 'ROLE_EXAMPLE1_ADMIN')")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<MyEntity> get() {
        return service.get();
    }

    
    @GetMapping("/getAllAuth")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_EXAMPLE1_ADMIN') or hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public List<MyEntity> getAuth() {
        return service.get();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAllAuth2")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_EXAMPLE1_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public List<MyEntity> getAuth2() {
        return service.get();
    }
}
```

However, I get denied in all of them. I tried both using roles and permissions.

For clarification, `EXAMPLE1_USER == ROLE_EXAMPLE1_USER`, and same with the others. I made sure it was not a typo.

Any idea on what the issue might be?

Comment: A 500 is an internal server error not an authentication issue. You should have a stack trace on the server in this scenario.

Comment: Mmm I'm not getting any error on the terminal, but I noticed I don't get many traces/logs (I'm kinda new with spring boot). Maybe the "default" run hides most of these? If so, how can I check all the traces?

Comment: Depends on your logger. If you are using spring boot by default you should be seeing INFO and ERROR messages.  Are you using one of the spring boot starters?  If you are using spring boot 1.x you may need to add a dependency

Comment: I'm not using any spring boot starter. I see the INFO and WARN logs, but only on launch, I don't see any other significant log after that (other than hibernate's succesfull queries)

Comment: Its possible you have an error handler that is eating the error. You could try attaching a debugger and stopping on caught exceptions. Otherwise you might try isolating exactly what code is failing and writing a test.

Comment: Yeah, I can access those with no problem, but I couldn't figure out how to bring out any stack trace yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by changing the `hasAnyRole` to `hasAnyAuthority` in both the annotations and the security file.